# Are "Book recommendations" allowed?

Tags: discussion, support, on-topic-off-topic

I see some questions from time to time which ask about book recommendations. I could not find anything related to the *book* term on the [faq](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) page. Is it allowed *or* should it be allowed?

Some examples I can give:

- [A Good Resource (Book, …) For Literary Techniques/Devices?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15300/a-good-resource-book-for-literary-techniques-devices)
- [Learning Phrasal verbs and idioms (Which book(s) would you recommend for them?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/learning-phrasal-verbs-and-idioms)
- [Books on articulation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/976/books-on-articulation)
- [What are some good books/online resources for growing your vocabulary?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7057/what-are-some-good-books-online-resources-for-growing-your-vocabulary)

Comment: can you provide URLs with examples of this? Otherwise it is theoretical..

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Please see my edit.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing as well. There [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/183/what-are-some-of-the-better-english-reference-grammars) but I'm more interested in books that are a bit more entertaining. (I'm currently reading *Woe is I* and have *Eats, Shoots, and Leaves* in the queue.) Those don't seem to fit in that question.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest since all these questions are requests for books about English Language and Usage, they are the sort of thing that should be encouraged. Recommendations about other books would, I'd think, be off-topic. (The one about Literary Techniques and Devices might be said to be stretching it a little, though.)

Comment: If they are allowed, I strongly recommend that our policy be to make the **comunity wiki**. This really seems like the kind of thing CW is for.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about books seem off-topic to me, because in those questions the topic is not (strictly speaking) English language, but a book about English language.
They seem also rather subjective or—in the case the question is not asking for a good book, the best book—questions where every answer is equally valid.

For these reasons, I would think questions about books and websites should not be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about Books and Websites should be allowed and it is allowed and worked very well on Stackoverflow where books programming books questions are frequently asked and also one with lots of votes.  If English Grammar books are considered off topic then shouldn't it be a rule for StackOverflow as well.

Please correct me if I am wrong.  I am new to Q & A sites.